# The result of [Datetime + 420./1440] (7 hours) is wrong (precision in ms is lost)

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

Could pls explain why I' not able to get valid result ( with precision to miliseconds ) after doing this (adding 7hrs to date):

```
select getdate() as dt into #t1
select dt, dt+(7.*60/1440) as dt_new from #t1
```

I got:

```
dt                      dt_new
2010-10-25 04:56:33.640 2010-10-25 11:56:33.580
```

As you can see there is difference in 60ms for dt_new - WHY?
AFAIR I WAS able to do this sort of things in Oracle 10g - even with minutes:
**`date + 5/1440`** -to produce 5-min periods of datetime.

***UPD:***

My mistake - the CORRECT way of doing this is:

```
select getdate(), getdate()+(convert(float, 5)/1440) as dt_new
```

I suppose there is wrong implicit convertion choosen by Ms Sql server.

**UPD2:**
Thanks for replies, but my point was "arifmetic" method - because there are cases when calculating dates ***without*** `dateadd` really improves Query Plan - by eliminating Table scan that is the case with Dateadd and other functions. 
Anyway it works - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the inbuilt functions, such as

```
select dt, DATEADD(hour, 7, dt) as dt_new from #t1
```

My guess as to the imprecision in using + is that its converting from datetime to integer, then back again.

Comment: No it is not Integer - because I got almost correct result but with small difference. With integer i'd got the same as initial value because 1/something = 0 for Integer type. I suppose it used a numeric or somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the even correcter way of adding 7 hours to a `datetime` is to use `DATEADD`:

```
select getdate() as dt into #t1
select dt, dateadd(hh, 7, dt) as dt_new from #t1
```

gives

```
dt                      dt_new
----------------------- -----------------------
2010-10-25 13:16:35.067 2010-10-25 20:16:35.067
```

Comment: +1 - this also drastically improves readability - a lot more obvious what the intention is

Comment: dateadd and other functions is not SARGable that's why i stick to Arifmetic's method. Especially when you add a constantto column - it could be taken into account by SQL Optimiser. dateadd - it's always TABLE scan.

Comment: @zmische your question features date manipulation only in the `SELECT` list, where I believe SARGability doesn't come into it - if you had said this was going to be in a `WHERE` clause, you might have got different answers...

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve better result with dateadd() function (like previous posters noted). If you want use arithmetics, use better datatype, like float - cast(7 as float) instead of 7. is working well.